# file_get_contents ailed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a new module, after run command its fails on /webpack.mix.js

php artisan module:make Demand

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUJnC.png)

What is the error and what should be done to fix it?

```
   ErrorException

  file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\kerman\amlak\vendor\nwidart\laravel-modules\src\Support/../Commands/stubs/webpack.stub): F
ailed to open stream: No such file or directory

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\kerman\amlak\vendor\nwidart\laravel-modules\src\Support\Stub.php:106
    102▕      * @return mixed|string
    103▕      */
    104▕     public function getContents()
    105▕     {
  ➜ 106▕         $contents = file_get_contents($this->getPath());
    107▕
    108▕         foreach ($this->replaces as $search => $replace) {
    109▕             $contents = str_replace('$' . strtoupper($search) . '$', $replace, $contents);
    110▕         }

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\kerman\amlak\vendor\nwidart\laravel-modules\src\Support\Stub.php:106
      file_get_contents("C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\kerman\amlak\vendor\nwidart\laravel-modules\src\Support/../Commands/stubs/webpack.stu
b")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\kerman\amlak\vendor\nwidart\laravel-modules\src\Support\Stub.php:122
      Nwidart\Modules\Support\Stub::getContents()
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for late response

Basically, this problem is happened when you changed your laravel version or package version

in my case I have found this problem solution is to removed config.php file from config directory and publish it again if needed (optional)

this is the command that you can use for publish your config file

```
php artisan vendor: publish --provider="PWParsons\PayGate\PayGateServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```